# Как изменить внешний вид option?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Как изменить внешний вид *< option>< /option>*? Например, вставить картинки или блоки вместо текста.

Answer (score 2):

При помощи jquery библиотек меняется внешний вид. К примеру вот такая есть: [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

Answer (score 1):

[Православно](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html) option не подразумевает в себе картинок или текста. Однако этот вопрос [решается](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).